# Bar diameter for Genesis Croix de fer 20 (2015)

Tags: road-bike, stem

I would like to switch my stem for angle adjustable one and I am having trouble identifying the clamp size for the [Gensis, Croix de Fer 20 (2015)](http://www.genesisbikes.co.uk/bikes/adventure/b-road/croix-de-fer-20).

I do not see the stem/bar clamp spec listed.

There are various adjustable road stems :

- [Ritchey adjustable road](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/ritchey-adjustable-road-stem/): 25.4mm bar clamp
- [Deda adjustable road](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/deda-adjustable-road-stem/) 31.8mm bar clamp

These both seem to be standard road stem/bar clamp sizes, I am not sure where to find which one Genesis use documented.

Comment: Do you have a caliper? You could remove the bars from the stem and measure the diameter at the clamping surface.

Comment: Or a piece of string, and note that the circumference will be pi*d, and it will be quite different between 31.8 mm and 25.4 mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to renesis and Batman, I used masking tape to measure bar clamping circumference.

```
100mm circumference => 31.8mm diameter.
```